# Alternative to DVD Player on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, dvd, media, software-rec, codec

DVD Player is probably the program I use that crashes the most. Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have already recommended it once tonight!

[VLC!](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)

It runs on Mac OSX and can play a stack of files including dvds all natively without requiring any third party codecs. - [here is a list of features](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/features.html)

Comment: I'm trying it now, and it seems ok but doesn't seem to recognize the DVD video chapters >:(

Comment: well, it didn't crash like DVD Player did so it gets my vote!

Comment: One of VLCs glaring omissions is the lack of support for forced subtitles.  Try watching the scenes in LOTR where they speak Elvish...

Comment: @Thruston - iso/video download or genuine blu-ray/dvd?

Comment: @WilliamHilsum Real commercial, paid-for-it-myself DVD.  The omission is a [known bug in VLC](https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/1135).

Answer (score 5):

A second vote for **[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)** here.

Chapters should be in **Playback menu > Chapters**

---

Another modern alternative is **[MPlayer OS X Extended](http://mplayerosx.sttz.ch/)**. I keep both installed because sometimes each is better at decoding particular files. MPlayer seems to use a bit less CPU sometimes too.

[image]

Comment: "That link (Mplayer OSX Extended) takes you to a place with bogus link to download something called Genieo which is adware. Beware."  -- [YourMother](http://superuser.com/users/297795/yourmother)

Answer (score 1):

[mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html) will play DVDs (and other media), but does not necessarily have the most Mac-like interface. I keep it around because it will run some files that quicktime won't. YMMV and all that.